# How to show other applications icons on a widget?

Tags: android, icons, widget

I'm trying to show some applications' icons on an Android widget.

I can get the icon as a drawable with:

```
Drawable d = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(appInfo);
```

but then I need to update the widget with the icon, and RemoteViews only accept Bitmap.

Anyway to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?

I've tried this but it didn't work

```
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(64, 
                    64, Config.RGB_565);

            Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);              

            d.draw(c);
```

I know it's possible since I've seen apps in the market that do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it: remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.icon1, ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap());